# What is the best way to create a FED reusable navigation component with routes and integrate that in all the library/framework based applications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, web-component, micro-frontend

1. The requirement is to create a reusable navigation component which will list links from the application which is gonna host this component?
2. The host application will be having router implementation of its own, like if I have this component in react project it will be based on react router dom. If I have this component in angular it will be angular routing.
3. How do I write a generic component to achieve this in any library or framework?
4. I tried using web component and achieved everything except this route thing?
5. Sharing history from host to component will not be the best way since react/angular uses different approach to history push state.
6. Plain window history push state is not working since library/frameworks are ignoring global push inside the application route state?

Any recommendation or help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.